# Geodesic deviation

Tags: general-relativity, differential-geometry, metric-tensor, linearized-theory

In [S. Carroll](http://preposterousuniverse.com/grnotes/) *Lecture Notes on General Relativity,* chapter 6, pages 152-153 we have equation
(6.62)
 $$\tag{6.62} \frac{\partial^2}{\partial t^2} S^\mu=\frac{1}{2} S^\sigma \frac{\partial^2}{\partial t^2} h^\mu_{\; \sigma}.$$

While trying to deduce that equation from the previous one
$$\tag{6.58} \frac{D^2}{d \tau^2} S^\mu= R^\mu_{\; \nu\rho\sigma} U^\nu U^\rho S^\sigma,$$
where $U^\mu$ is the velocity vector I noticed that he neglected the term
 $$\tag{*}\frac{\partial}{\partial \tau}(U^\rho \Gamma^\mu_{\; \rho \sigma} S^\sigma)$$ 
on the left hand side.

Is this approximation justified in his setting? Or am I mistaken somewhere?

Comment: Related: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/117421/2451

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the ∗ term is incomplete. The two total $D$-derivatives on the lhs. of eq. (6.58) in Ref. 1 is what is causing the curvature on the rhs. in the first place, see e.g. Ref. 2 p. 146.

Carroll is on the lhs. eq. (6.62) changing notation for the two total $D$-derivatives to two $\partial$-derivatives, but they are still total derivatives.

In fluid-dynamical language, one may say that Carroll is going from an [Eulerian to a Lagrangian picture](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrangian_and_Eulerian_specification_of_the_flow_field).

He is considering linearized gravity, so the Riemann curvature tensor is proportional to $\epsilon$, and we can (to the order that we are calculating, namely to first order in $\epsilon$) interpret $S^{\sigma}$ on the rhs. as following the flow.

Note that Ref. 2 contains slightly more details than Ref. 1.

References:

1. Sean Carroll, *[Lecture Notes on General Relativity](http://preposterousuniverse.com/grnotes/),* Chapter 6. The pdf file is available [here](http://preposterousuniverse.com/grnotes/grnotes-six.pdf).
2. Sean Carroll, *[Spacetime and Geometry: An Introduction to General Relativity](http://preposterousuniverse.com/spacetimeandgeometry/),* 2003; Chapter 7.

Comment: Would you please clarify more, where am I wrong exactly?

Comment: The $*$ term is incomplete. The complete term would just lead to the curvature term on the rhs. of eq. (6.58).